# $\alpha = 2, \beta=\sqrt3 + i, \gamma=1+i$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find $r, \theta$ of $\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\gamma}$

For $z=a+bi=re^{i\theta}$, with $ r = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} $ and $\theta= \tan^{-1}\frac{b}{a}$.
What is $a,b$ in $\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\gamma}$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate,

$$\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\gamma}=\frac{2+\sqrt3+i}{1+i}
=(\sqrt3 +1)e^{-i\frac \pi6}
$$

where the followings are used,

$$2+\sqrt3+i=\sqrt2(\sqrt3+1)e^{i\frac {\pi}{12}}$$
$$\frac{1}{1+i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} e^{-i\frac \pi4}$$

Thus, $r=\sqrt3+1$ and $\theta = -\frac\pi6$.

$$a= \frac{3+\sqrt3}{2},\>\>\>\>\>b= -\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2}$$

——————-

Edit:

To avoid $\pi/12$, evaluate instead

$$\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\gamma}
=\frac{2+\sqrt3+i}{1+i}=\frac 12 (2+\sqrt3 +i)(1-i)
=\frac 12 [3+\sqrt3 -(\sqrt3+1)i]$$

Then,

$$ r = \frac 12 \sqrt{ (3+\sqrt3)^2+(\sqrt3+1)^2}
= \sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}=\sqrt3+1$$

$$\theta =\tan^{-1}-\frac{\sqrt3+1}{3+\sqrt3}=-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt3}=-\frac\pi6$$

Comment: $$2+\sqrt3+i=\sqrt2(\sqrt3+1)e^{i\frac {\pi}{12}}$$
$$\frac{1}{1+i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} e^{-i\frac \pi4}$$
How it become like this? No calculator allowed, sin 15 cos 15?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+i} = \frac{i-1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}e^{-i\tan^{-1}\frac{-1}{1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}e^{-i\frac \pi4}$.

Comment: I added another approach to avoid 15 degrees

Comment: Why i always get $\tan \theta ^{-1}= -\sqrt 3$ ?

Comment: Sorry, the numerator and denominator should be switched. I corrected it.

Comment: Why the answer not 150 and 330? Tan 150 = -1/sqrt3 ? = tan 330 ?

Comment: Since a > 0 and b < 0, z is in the 4th quadrant. So, $\theta$ can not be 150. Here, we follow the principal value domain convention, which defines $\theta$ within (-180, 180).

Comment: So i can answer 330?

Comment: Yeah, you could. Just make sure there is no implicit assumption regarding the domain

Comment: I keep getting arctan $\theta = -\sqrt 3$ are you sure bout your answer? And $r=\sqrt{4-\sqrt 3}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiply the expression $\frac{\alpha + \beta}{\gamma}$ by $\frac{\overline{\gamma}}{\overline{\gamma}}$, where $\overline{\gamma} = 1- i$, and simplify. Note that $\gamma \overline{\gamma}$ is a real number.

Answer (score -1):

[image][image]

After editing the question new answers is

Comment: This is not right since $i$ is missing in your third line. But even if it is right, please type your answer in MathJax.

Comment: I don't know ; how to write in mathjex in mobile

Comment: By the way You are right